# Find Elements By background in WebView2 C#

Tags: c#, jquery, webview2

I'm trying the following code to get an element with specific background-

```
    private async void myWebView_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string script = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(@"jquery.min.js");
        await myWebView.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);
    }

    private async Task ExtractAsync()
    {
        //the following line is ok.
        var str = await myWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync(" $('.container p:eq(2)').html();");

        //but str is null in the following line-
        var str = await myWebView.ExecuteScriptAsync("var element = $('.container p:eq(2)'); if($(element).css('background')=='green'){return 'green';}else{return 'not green';}");
    }
```

Any help?